# Node: in memory cache comparison

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, server

I have a script that collects data from 2 APIs and stores the response in a file. It runs every minute so I'm trying to now optimize my script by cacheing the first response and checking that any part of the second response isn't the same before saving the file.

I'm running into issues with converting the cache into something readable. I'm using `res.on('data' ...` that is called more than once.

Is there a better way to compare the two responses before saving? Can I convert the data into something human readable without using `res.on('data'`?

Thanks for any help!

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var cachedResponse;

function cash(res) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var data = '';
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
      data += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
      cachedResponse = data;
      resolve(cachedResponse);
    });
  });
}

function download(url, dest, cb) {
  var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
  var request = https
    .get(url, function(res) {
      var oldCache = cachedResponse;
      cash(res).then(res => {
        console.log('CACHED', oldCache, res);
        // check that new response doesn't equal oldCache before saving
         res.pipe(file);
         file.on('finish', function() {
           file.close(cb); // close() is async, call cb after close completes.
         });
      });
    })
    .on('error', function(err) {
      // Handle errors
      fs.unlink(dest); // Delete the file async. (But we don't check the result)
      if (cb) cb(err.message);
    });
}

var downloadStationAndPoints = function() {
  var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
  var stationsUrl = 'https://url/stations/stations.json';
  var pointsUrl = 'https://url/scores';
  var stationsDest = `${__dirname}/data/stations_${timestamp}_.json`;
  var pointsDest = `${__dirname}/data/points_${timestamp}_.json`;
  var cb = function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('error in download at time:', timestamp, ', message:', err);
    }
  };
  download(stationsUrl, stationsDest, cb);
  download(pointsUrl, pointsDest, cb);
};

// run

setInterval(() => {
  downloadStationAndPoints();
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

1、could you compare the `content-length` from the response header of apis before you compare the body contents?

2、you can use `buf.compare()` to compare the content before encoding.

3、`https.get` is asynchronous, as your code, `cachedResponse` may written interleave with two requests.

Hope these will be useful to you.